# Why are these mounted different directories with the same inode number?

Tags: linux, unix

In Linux, `.` and `..` have the same inode number only in 2 situations:

1. `.` and `..` in the *root of the root filesystem* has the same inode number.
2. `.` and `..` in the *mount directory of a newly mounted filesystem on a directory of root filesystem* has the same inode number.

But when I check the inode on CentOS7 I find a mounted directory has the same inode number with the root directory of the root filesystem.

Such as below, the `/boot` directory has the same inode number as `/`. In addition, other directories such as `/sys/bus/memory/drivers` and `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_stat/function20` are also has the same inode with `/`.(inode number is 64).

```sh
[root@localhost boot]# mount
/dev/mapper/centos-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
...
```

```sh
[root@localhost boot]# find / -inum 64
/
/boot
/sys/bus/memory/drivers
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_stat/function20
```

the tree joint part

```sh
[root@localhost ~]# ls -ai /
      64 .        64 ..       64 boot
```

If they have the same inode number, how does kernel find the correct content? or these directories should point to the same content (but different files under these directories)? or it only happens with LVM directories?

Does anyone know why this happened? Do I make a mistake or get something wrong here?

Comment: `/boot` is a different file system of the same type (xfs), and it's the root directory of this file system, so it's very likely that it uses the same inode number as `/`. The inode number must be unique within the same file system only. `/sys` is a special virtual file system, the rules for real file systems may not apply here.

Comment: Inode values are only unique within a filesystem.  Filesystems can move between computers - take a USB drive, create a filesystem on it, then move the USB drive to another computer.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks a lot for your answer.  

The `/boot` and `/` are the different mounting point of different filesystems, and they can have the same inode number of its filesystem root. 

But I am wondering the (`/` and `/boot`) filesystem tree joint part in `/` directory. As you can see the `boot` directory is under `/` directory, and the `boot` directory displays the same inode number as `.` and `..` in `/` directory. So there are three directories (`.`, `..`, `/boot`) with the same inode number in `/`. The Linux kernel can still distinguish them, hum..., is that normal?

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thanks for your practical test suggestion, I will try it and have a look. but I still have some wonders about the tree joint part, as described above.

Comment: Try `umount /boot` and then `ls -ai /`. I guess it will then show a different inode number for `boot` because it then refers to the directory in `/` instead of the root directory of the XFS file system in `/dev/sda1`.